# Posso usar o Layout Grid CSS em todos os novos projetos?

Tags: css, html5, layout, grid

Mesmo sem suporte integral por parte dos navegadores microsoft, sendo necessário o uso do prefixo -ms-, posso começar a usar Grids CSS em novos projetos sem me preocupar ou devo continuar usando os grids frameworks ?

Comment: Isso depende de você e de quem é seu público. Se grande parte dele utilizar navegadores que já suportam e você não se importa dos poucos que não utilizam verem sua página desconfigurada, pode usar. Se quer entregar o mesmo produto para todos os usuários, precisará de outras ferramentas além do CSS Grid.

Answer (score 0):

**Depende do projeto**

Todo projeto tende ter um planejamento. Ele engloba os recursos, requisitos e o público/client. Você deve analisar o seu *cenário*, se seus usuários já tem suporte e em grande parte tem navegadores atuais, vale a pena usar, caso algum não tenha, vai ter uma péssima experiência vendo a página toda "bagunçada".  Eu aconselho manter suporte a navegadores desatualizados sim, as vezes sair inovando acaba com a UX.

**Dica:**

Use o site [can i use](https://caniuse.com/) para pesquisa de compatibilidade em navegadores.